# Automatically generate word doc from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a custom word doc per excel sheet. I started with having a button (which I might change to hyperlink) and the corresponding macro looks like the one given below. But the whole process takes an insane amount of time, my word and excel gets stuck while the operation takes place even for a very small excel sheet with hardly 16 rows. Is there any better way to do this better and speed up the process?

```
Sub test()
    Dim word As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set word = GetObject(, "word.application") 
    If Err = 429 Then
        Set word = CreateObject("word.application") 
        Err.Clear
    End If
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    With word
        .Documents.Add
        .Selection.Paste
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This took about 2 seconds on my computer with a blank excel sheet with 16 cells filled. I guess there is something different going on with your computer? Try changing things and see if you can figure out what is making it slow. First just try rebooting and trying again. Then maybe try with an instance of word already open and with none open and see if it is different? Try just creating an instance of word with code (`Set word = CreateObject("word.application") `) and then setting `word.visible = true` and see how long it takes. Then you will know if it is the copying that is slow...etc...

Comment: You can remove the Activate step by doing `Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy` but that won't fix your problem. The creation of a new document is likely what is slowing you down. No way around that. Maybe it would be faster to just select all delete and then paste save as. Removes the new doc step.

Comment: Its the potential for confusion with the Word object should the OP ever add a reference to the Word Object library rather than using a late bound object.  I'd at least use the variable name myWord so that there is no opportunity for confusion.  Naming of variables using Key words is just plain stupid.

Comment: I did say 'lets not dwell'

Answer (score 0):

I would try avoiding the use of `Selection`. Try this code and see if it performs better for you.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.application")
    If Err = 429 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
        Err.Clear
    End If
    Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Copy
    With wdApp
        .Documents.Add.Content.Paste
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```